# Grub rescue is booting everytime instead of my windows 10 recovery flash drive HELP

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

So my linux experience started off by abandoning windows for a week and trying ubuntu 17.04.

then i wanted to switch back to windows so i downloaded an iso file to put it on my flash drive using etcher and when i tried to boot the flash drive it always booted ubuntu instead.

so idiot me had the idea of deleting the ubuntu partition so i did that and then rebooted and im stuck in grub rescue
it says:

```
error: file'/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your flash drive to be the first boot drive?

To do that you have to insert your flash drive (it is USB, right?), reboot the computer, during the boot press <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> or something else (depends on model of your computer) to get to BIOS (or UEFI) menu. Then find boot options and move your USB drive before your hard drive, then choose "Save settings and exit".

Comment: Yes i  have done that and made the os boot manager and the hdd present in my computer lastin the boot order

Comment: But it still doesnt boot the usb

Comment: I have not tried to boot windows from a USB stick for a long time if ever... Don't remember how it works. I would put Ubuntu to the USB stick and try to boot it. That way you'll know is it your Windows flash that causes the problem (if Ubuntu does boot from USB) , or your computer boot settings (if Ubuntu doesn't boot either).